# How to delete all the Existing tables in DynamoDb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I wants to delete all the existing tables in my database in DynamoDb?

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: A pity that AWS forces you to delete them one at a time with a silly radio button !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Manually go into the AWS console and delete every table
2. Programmatically by calling [`ListTables`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.html) (multiple calls if pagination is needed), iterate through the resulting [**TableNames**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.html#DDB-ListTables-response-TableNames), and call [`DeleteTable`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteTable.html) for each one.

Comment: If the context is Java...if one has a variable, `amazonDynamoDB` (of type AmazonDynamoDB), a Java 8 one-liner to do #2 is: `amazonDynamoDB.listTables().getTableNames().stream().forEach(amazonDynamoDB::deleteTable)`

Answer (score 13):

You can use aws cli to delete all tables, may be except one table.

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --profile your_profile | jq .'TableNames[]' -r | grep -v table_you_dont_want_to_delete | xargs -ITABLE -n 1 aws dynamodb delete-table --table-name TABLE --profile your_profile
```

Answer (score 6):

You can delete table using below code.

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'table-name',
};
dynamodb.deleteTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) ppJson(err); // an error occurred
    else ppJson(data); // successful response
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Javascript to delete *all* tables

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk")

AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-west-2",
  endpoint: process.env.DYNAMODB_URL
})

var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

dynamodb.listTables({}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.error(err, err.stack)
  for (tableName of data.TableNames) {
    dynamodb.deleteTable({TableName: tableName}, function(err, data) {
      if (err) console.error(err, err.stack)
      else console.log('Deleted', tableName)
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The new UI console (2020) now allows you to select multiple tables and delete.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'json'
tables=JSON.parse(`aws dynamodb list-tables`)["TableNames"]

tables.each do |table|
  `aws dynamodb delete-table  --table-name #{table}`
  sleep 2 # Only 10 tables can be created, updated, or deleted simultaneously
  puts "#{table} deleted"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete all the DynamoDB tables having a specific keyword in their names, simply run the following CLI commands:

```
tableList=$(aws dynamodb list-tables | jq .'TableNames[]' -r | grep tableNameKeyword)
for table in $tableList; do aws dynamodb delete-table --table-name $table ; done
```